# Normal subgroup but not characteristic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know every characteristic subgroup is normal subgroup but converse is not true.  I find an example in Klien 4- group.

But I have seen on internet that in Q$_8$,  each of cyclic subgroup of order 4 is normal (as index 2)  but none of these is characteristic.

There are 3 subgroups of order 4 in Q$_8$,  how can I show these 3 subgroups are  not characteristic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an automorphism $\phi$ of $Q_8=\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ which cyclically permutes $i,j,k$:
$$\phi(\pm 1)=\pm 1, \phi(\pm i)=\pm j, \phi(\pm j)=\pm k, \phi(\pm k)=\pm i$$
So $\phi$ does not preserve any of the three (cyclic) order-4 subgroups $\{1,i,-1,-i\},\{1,j,-1,-j\}, \{1,k,-1,-k\}$ of $Q_8$.

Comment: Very good,,, I understand clearly